# How to see Mac OS X scripts running?

Tags: mac-osx

An LDAP server on another is reporting an unusually large number of attempts to read the LDAP directory, all of which look like hacking attempts to read user/password information. It reports that the originating IP is a Mac OS X server. I log into the Mac OS X server, run `ps -A` but it does nothing looks suspicious. Is there a way to see what the Mac OS X ldap client is doing?

I need to disable this malicious script, but I cannot disable the LDAP client completely, as users rely on this server for file storage and user ids.

Answer (score 0):

On the server: you can use `tcpdump` to sniff some packets from Mac OS X client:

```
# tcpdump -vv -s0 -i eth0 tcp port 389 and src host <mac.osx.ip.address>
```

and open with Wireshark to analyse.

On the client, use `netstat` to find out what process is connecting to LDAP server:

```
# netstat -natp | awk '$5 ~ /ldap.server.ip.address/ { print $0 }'
```

Comment: The Mac is OS X 10.4 (Tiger), and netstat's -p option is for specifying a protocol, not for listing a process. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: `sudo lsof -i:ldap` will show you processes using port 389 (both in and out) on OS X 10.4.